# Android - Material Theme

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

I'm trying to implement Material Theme with SDK 4.0.0. Here are some issues I have:

1. 9 patch splash (background.9.png) isn't displayed correctly. Worked fine before (logo centered with all white background, no black spots).

[image]

2. here is my custom theme:

```
<style name="MyMaterial" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#4CAF50</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#388E3C</item>
</style>
```

There are some windows opened dynamically that I want to have different colorPrimary/colorPrimaryDark than the defaults above. Is it possible?

3. My app uses a tab group. There is a underline underneath an active tab. I want to change the underline's color to #ffffff without affecting other controls' active color. Unfortunately colorAccent affects all controls' color. What should I do?
4. Can I remove the default tab divider and add shadow underneath so that the tabs look like the Google Play Store app's?
5. My app uses push notification. I usually specify my appicon.png for the notification's icon. Now upgraded to SDK 4.0.0 with Material Theme, the appicon shown in the notification becomes all white. Can I show the regular appicon instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since Android 5.0, you need to provide the until then optional padding box for nine-patch images. The newest version of the TiCons CLI generates this for you: http://npmjs.com/package/ticons. You need black pixels on the bottom and right side of the image, except for the bottom left + right and top right pixel.
2. You can define multiple themes and then use the `theme` property in `createWindow()` to select one.
3. Android's new Material Design Theme has limited options in what you can style. See https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html
4. See previous
5. Not sure about this one but did you check http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Sending_and_Scheduling_Push_Notifications-section-43298780_SendingandSchedulingPushNotifications-icon?

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you! However, I can't believe for #3 and #4 I can't do anything.... For #5, yes I explicitly specify my appicon to be the notification icon. Somehow the system makes it all white automatically....

Comment: Filling the 9-patch padding to almost max, leaving out a single pixel edge, did the trick for me.